# Kernel Level and User Level Threads

Tags: pthreads, clone

Clone (Linux) creates a kernel level thread while PThreads creates a user level thread.
I have the feeling that some OSs does not actually support the user level threads. As an example:
On a dual core processor, if I have 2 running processes where the first one has 3 threads and the second one has 4 threads, then the time slots of the CPU won't be divided into 7 equal slots each to a single thread BUT one core will be allotted to process 1 and shared among its 3 threads, while the other core will be allotted to process 2 and shared among its 4 threads.

While if we use clone (on linux) rather than PThreads. Then the time of the dual core processor will be shared equally across the different kernel threads (7).

Is this TRUE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a description of the [NPTL library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library) most commonly used today:

> NPTL is a so-called 1×1 threads library, in that threads created by
>   the user (via the pthread_create() library function) are in 1-1
>   correspondence with schedulable entities in the kernel (tasks, in the
>   Linux case). This is the simplest possible threading implementation.

If they are schedulable entities by the kernel, then they can be scheduled individually on any processor, and your statement is not true.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I said that: (I have the feeling that some OSs does not actually support the user level threads). I meant some OSs not all of them. Let me restate my question in different way:
Is there any OS which works as I explained NOT according to the NPTL logic (which is meant for linux)

Comment: Of course there are, but I was answering the part about pthreads being user-level threads (It is not today). Can you be more specific? I can't give you a list of every single OS in existence on every architecture.

Comment: I do not need every single OS! I just need one example. I asked if there is any OS which works in my logic (NOT all of them). My main aim is to show that kernel level threads is better than user level thread in one aspect that is whenever you take your program, execution will be the same as all (current) OSs will consider the Kernel level threads. But for user-level threads, some OS work as I said while some other works as NPTL logic. This was my aim. So, one example of an OS is enough. Regards

Comment: Look up Java's green threads. They are no longer used today in most implementations, but provide an example of per-process userspace threading and its benefits/problems.